# Transpose records into records from 3 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transpose

I have 3 tables in Medical database,

table: member

```
    id_member    name
    1            Pendi
    2            Ardi
    3            Hafiz
    4            Arista
```

table: benefit

```
    id_member              id_benefit     year
    1                      1              2016
    1                      2              2016
    1                      3              2016
    2                      4              2016
    2                      5              2016
    2                      6              2016
    3                      7              2016
    3                      8              2016
    3                      9              2016
    4                      10             2016
    4                      11             2016
    4                      12             2016
```

table: masterbenefit

```
 id_masterbenefit       benefit_name        benefit_value
    1                      inpatient           100000
    2                      outpatient          2000
    3                      dental              300
    4                      inpatient           150000
    5                      outpatient          2500
    6                      dental              350
    7                      inpatient           170000
    8                      outpatient          2750
    9                      dental              375
    10                     inpatient           190000
    11                     outpatient          2900
    12                     dental              390
```

I want to display in one table

```
No.  Member-Name     Year       Inpatient        Outpatient     Dental
1.   Pendi           2016       100000           2000           300
2.   Ardi            2016       150000           2500           350
3.   Hafiz           2016       170000           2750           375
4.   Arista          2016       190000           2900           390
```

I have query like this (from other question in this site), but it is not that I need.

```
SELECT A.name NAME,
CASE WHEN B.id_benefit='1' THEN C.benefit_value END Inpatient,
CASE WHEN B.id_benefit='2' THEN C.benefit_value END Outpatient,
CASE WHEN B.id_benefit='3' THEN C.benefit_value END Dental,
CASE WHEN B.id_benefit='4' THEN C.benefit_value END Inpatient,
CASE WHEN B.id_benefit='5' THEN C.benefit_value END Outpatient,
CASE WHEN B.id_benefit='6' THEN C.benefit_value END Dental,
CASE WHEN B.id_benefit='7' THEN C.benefit_value END Inpatient,
CASE WHEN B.id_benefit='8' THEN C.benefit_value END Outpatient,
CASE WHEN B.id_benefit='9' THEN C.benefit_value END Dental,
CASE WHEN B.id_benefit='10' THEN C.benefit_value END Inpatient,
CASE WHEN B.id_benefit='11' THEN C.benefit_value END Outpatient,
CASE WHEN B.id_benefit='12' THEN C.benefit_value END Dental,
FROM member A, benefit B, masterbenefit C
WHERE A.id_member=B.id_member
AND B.id_benefit=C.id_masterbenefit
GROUP BY A.id_member
ORDER BY A.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Joins` to combine data and `group by` for grouping data for each member:

Try this:

```
select 
  @row_num:=@row_num+1 as no,
  m.name,
  b.year,
  max(if(mb.benefit_name='inpatient',mb.benefit_value,0)) as inpatient,
  max(if(mb.benefit_name='outpatient',mb.benefit_value,0)) as outpatient,
  max(if(mb.benefit_name='dental',mb.benefit_value,0)) as dental
from member m
inner join benefit b on m.id_member=b.id_member
inner join masterbenefit mb on b.id_benefit=mb.id_masterbenefit,(select @row_num:=0) as p
group by m.id_member,b.year
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e1250/3

Comment: Great! it works! it show what I need. Perfect. Thank You very much.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if you find it correct as this can be a reference for future visitors.